# How to map right Alt to Context-Menu key

Tags: windows-7, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, parallels

I'm running Windows 8.1 through Parallels Desktop 8 on a MacBook Pro with Mavericks. Windows keyboards have a key that simulates a mouse right click at the place where the caret for typing is. Since this is a windows phenomenon, my MBP keyboard has no such key. I'd like to map the right hand Alt for this purpose. (Who needs two Alts anyway?)

How can this be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com).

When you Launch Autohotkey, it will asks you the following:

> To help you get started, would you like to create a sample script in the My Documents folder?

Press YES to create and display the sample script.

This will create a `AutoHotkey.ahk` file in your `Documents` Folder. Open `AutoHotkey.ahk` with notepad and add the following to the end of the file.

```
RAlt::Appskey
```

Now run the script by opening the `AutoHotkey.ahk` file with the **Autohotkey** application you installed before.

Now when you press the **right Alt key** you will see the ContextMenu.

Comment: It's a great solution, but you shouldn't remap it to the `Rbutton` itself. Use `AppsKey` instead, it was created exactly for the context menu thing. ([source](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm))

Comment: @IOXenus, what do you mean I should use AppsKey? What is AppsKey?

Comment: @Robino, `AppsKey` - this is the key that invokes the right-click context menu.

Comment: @Robino, I have updated the answer so that the right alt keys is mapped to the `Appskey` that IOXenus is talking about.

Comment: Sorry it has taken almost 2 years to test this solution but I am happy to announce it works as required. In fact the Rbutton is closer to the desired behaviour.

Comment: No it's not. Appskey is what I wanted. Doh!

Comment: @Ishan Adding a shortcut to the script to the "startup" folder ensures this is run on login and remains a permanent feature. No more "Shift+F10" for me!