# Is there a way to switch the right Ctrl key with the mouse's right click in the new Lenovo X1 Carbon?

Tags: thinkpad

Hi I need to have the mouse right click tab instead of the right Ctrl. The key I need generally appear with a small window and the mouse arrow printed on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to map right Alt to Context-Menu key](https://superuser.com/questions/710601/how-to-map-right-alt-to-context-menu-key)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is similar to ([How to map right Alt to Context-Menu key](https://superuser.com/questions/710601/how-to-map-right-alt-to-context-menu-key))

It says that a program called AutoHotKey may fit your needs.